# React-Code-Splitting Not Working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, code-splitting-async

After reading [this post](https://hackernoon.com/straightforward-code-splitting-with-react-and-webpack-4b94c28f6c3f), I tried to use [react-code-splitting](https://github.com/didierfranc/react-code-splitting) to splite my JavaScript bundle.

```
Webpack Version: 3.10.10
```

#### PageRouter.js

```
import Async from "react-code-splitting";
import React from "react";
// import Home from "pages/home/Home";
// ...

const Home = () => <Async load={import("pages/home/Home")} />

export default class PageRouter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

### Webpack Dev Server Error

It seems like just a syntax problem?

```
export default class PageRouter extends React.Component {
    render() {
             ^
        return (...);
    }
}
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial video I found on using react-loadable library for splitting code in create react app which worked for me -
 https://youtu.be/AR5GSZuox1k

Comment: Here is a blog on medium regarding code splitting - https://medium.com/prod-io/code-splitting-in-react-using-webpack-1aa1014da216

Comment: Modern React JS applications use React.lazy() and Suspense for lazy loading and code splitting. This video shows how to do that in great detail: https://youtu.be/j8NJc60H294

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell what the root issue is but, I suspect that perhaps you are missing some babel plugins. Check out [Paragons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-paragons). It uses React Loadable. You can cross check the [webpack config](https://github.com/joseki-tech/generator-paragons/blob/master/generators/app/templates/paragons-template/webpack.config.js) and examine the usage:

Start from:

```
export const CodeSplitPageLoadable = createLoadable('./demo/components/CodeSplitPage')
```

in [routes.js](https://github.com/joseki-tech/generator-paragons/blob/master/generators/app/templates/paragons-template/src/shared/routes.js).